# Are Deduping Rules working for Contact Subtypes?

Tags: core

I have created an Individual Subtype (named "Child"), for children (who don't have mail address).

Although I specified a matching rule (first name / last name) in the creation Webform (I use Webform Integration), I have some duplicates (???).

And if I want to dedupe/merge those (using this same dedupe rule), I don't find them.

Do dedupe rules only work for Contact Types and not for Subtypes ?

Comment: Hi, @Jacques, what is the version of CiviCRM you are using? I just tried to reproduce your problem on the [demo](http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org) but did not succeed. As far as I can see is subtype just another attribute, although it does not show on the merge screen. I managed to merge to individuals with a different subtype.

Comment: Can you please specify also what your rule looks like (with the weights, total, and length in use for each name)?

Comment: Thank you Kainuk : Drupal 7.51 / Civi 4.7.12 ; Subtype is standard Individual Subtype. Thank you Allen : my rule is {first name (weight 2) ; last name (weight 2) ; Total weight 4 ; length is empty ; supervised} (those are children, with no mail)

Comment: I've been wondering if dedupe is working correctly in 4.7.12 with a large data set.  (WP rather than Drupal.)  Been testing with groups and keep getting 0 back, when it should have anywhere from two to thousands.  Using pre-built rules doesn't seem to change the results.  Haven't locked it down enough yet to even begin to create a bug report, much less reproducible results on the demo site.